# How to switch between radians and degrees in SAS

Tags: math, sas, trigonometry, degrees, radians

just looking for an easy way to run trig functions in SAS without having to manually correct in each calculation.  Below is what I am working with.

I am running this in SAS 9 probably, the SAS Studio Student Module but this is a general SAS question.

I have manually created a variable, 'rad' in the 'calc' data step to deal with this but it adds a step of complexity that I would like to avoid.

I am asking whether there is a system setting, alternate trig function or ... ? that would change the calculation from:
`bh_x = cos(rad*bh_a)*bh_l    ;`
to:
`bh_x = cos(bh_a)*bh_l    ;`
so I don't have to manually convert my angle in degrees to radians for the trig function to work.

Thanks to anyone reading this and putting any mental effort to the solution!
Tim

```
data spec   ;
    length
        b2h_a 8
        b2h_l 8
        b2h_l_e 8
        bike $ 8
        name $ 16
    ;
    input
        bike $
        name $
        bh_a
        bh_l
        ht_a
        spcr
        st_h
        st_a
        st_l
        hb_r
        hb_a
    ;
    datalines   ;
        srcn (0,0) 0 0 67 0 0 0 0 0 0
        srcn c 41 658 71.5 27 40 25 120 100 13
        srcn ne_27_n13 41 658 71.5 27 40 27 127 100 13
        srcn ne_15_0 41 658 71.5 15 40 27 127 100 0
        srcn ne_5_0 41 658 71.5 5 40 27 127 100 0 
        srcn ne_2_n9 41 658 71.5 2 40 27 127 100 9
        srcn ne_5_10 41 658 71.5 5 40 27 127 100 -10
        srcn ne_10_rf10 41 658 71.5 10 40 27 127 20 -10
        srcn max 41 658 90 250 0 0 250 0 0
    ;
run ;

data calc   ;
    set spec    ;

    pi=constant('pi')   ;
    rad=pi/180  ;

    bh_x = cos(rad*bh_a)*bh_l   ;
    bh_y = sin(rad*bh_a)*bh_l   ;

    sr_x = (cos(rad*ht_a)*(spcr+st_h/2))*-1 ;
    sr_y = sin(rad*ht_a)*(spcr+st_h/2);

    st_x = cos(rad*(90-ht_a+st_a))*st_l ;
    st_y = sin(rad*(90-ht_a+st_a))*st_l ;

    hb_x = cos(rad*(90-hb_a))*hb_r*-1   ;
    hb_y = sin(rad*(90-hb_a))*hb_r  ;

    hd_x = bh_x + sr_x + st_x + hb_x    ;
    hd_y = bh_y + sr_y + st_y + hb_y    ;

    if hd_x=0 then do   ;
        b2h_a=0 ;
        b2h_l=0 ;
    end ;
    else do ;
        b2h_a = atan(hd_y/hd_x)/rad ;
        b2h_l = hd_y/sin(b2h_a*rad) ;
    end ;

    b2h_l_e = b2h_l/25.4    ;

    drop pi rad ;

    format
        b2h_a 5.
        b2h_l 5.
        b2h_l_e 5.
        bh_a 5.
        bh_l 5.
        ht_a 5.
        spcr 5.
        st_h 5.
        st_a 5.
        st_l 5.
        hb_r 5.
        hb_a 5.
        bh_x 5.
        bh_y 5.
        sr_x 5.
        sr_y 5.
        st_x 5.
        st_y 5.
        hb_x 5.
        hb_y 5.
        hd_x 5.
        hd_y 5.
        b2h_a 5.
        b2h_l 5.
        b2h_l_e 5.1
        ;

run ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no trig functions in SAS that accept DEGREE or GRADIAN arguments.  You always need to convert from your data's angular measurement system to RADIAN.

You can write a macro to perform the conversion. Example:

```
%macro cosD(theta);
  %* theta is angle in degrees;
  %* emit data step source code that performs conversion from degrees to radians;
  cos(&theta*constant('PI')/180)
%mend;
```

In use:

```
data calc   ;
    set spec    ;

    bh_x = %cosD(bh_a) * bh_l   ;
```

You could convert the angular data to radians during the step where `input` occurs and then not have to worry about it again.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I think both suggestions will work to help clear the degree to radian conversion from the thought process.  I appreciate your help!